# Mongoose aggregate and get likes count

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm having a query pertaining to Mongoose aggregation. I've been trying to fetch user details along with like and love count separately and as well as its relations but I'm unable to succeed.

Here is my scenario, I have a user table and reaction table. User table holds user details and reaction table contains user details along with additional information like who liked the user. In my schema it's type eg: type='like' or love, so I need to get user details along with number of likes. I'm new to MongoDB.

Here is my code:

**User Schema**

```
// Importing Node packages required for schema
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const validateEmail = function(email) {
  const re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  return re.test(email)
};
//= ===============================
// User Schema
//= ===============================
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
  },
  reactions : [
    { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProfileReaction' }
  ],
},
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**Reaction Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  const ProfileReactionSchema = new Schema({
    likedBy: { 
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'User',
      required: true,
      index: true
    },
    user: { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User',
        required: true,
        index: true
      },
    type: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
    {
      timestamps: true // Saves createdAt and updatedAt as dates. createdAt will be our timestamp.
    }
);

  module.exports = mongoose.model('ProfileReaction', ProfileReactionSchema);
```

What I really want is something like below

```
{
   _id: '1234',
   email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
   reactions: [
      {
         _id: '1235',
         likedBy: {...},
         user: {...},
         type: 'like'
      },
      {
         _id: '1236',
         likedBy: {...},
         user: {...},
         type: 'love'
      }
   ],
   noOfLikes: 1,
   noOfLoves: 1
}
```

What I've tried so far is but this is giving me only the relations but I'm not getting the count of likes and love. But I need both of them likes count, loves count and relations

```
const user = await User.findOne({$or: [
    req.params.id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/) ? {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)}
    : {uid: req.params.id}
    ]}).populate([
      {
        path: 'reactions',
        model: 'ProfileReaction',
        populate: [
          {
            path: 'likedBy',
            model: 'User'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]);
```

I'm using version `mongoose v5.6.10`.

Comment: Quick reminder: there's no need to add "please help me" or other begging messages to your questions. Readers know you need help, and cries of woe intended to elicit sympathy may strike the reader as coercive. Remember that helpers are mostly volunteers here. Similarly, you do not need to invite readers to comment if they need clarification - surely as a 17k user you don't think readers are unaware of how the site operations. Please try to stick to technical writing. Stack Overflow is not a chat room `:-)`.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs and corrections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below `$lookup` aggregation

```
User.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$or": [
      req.params.id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)
        ? { "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) }
        : { "uid": req.params.id }
    ]
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": ProfileReaction.collection.name,
    "let": { "reactions": "$reactions" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": { "$in": ["$_id", "$$reactions"] },
        "type": "like"
      }}
    ],
    "as": "likeReactions"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": ProfileReaction.collection.name,
    "let": { "reactions": "$reactions" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": { "$in": ["$_id", "$$reactions"] },
        "type": "love"
      }}
    ],
    "as": "loveReactions"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "noOfLikes": { "$size": "$likeReactions" },
    "noOfLoves": { "$size": "$loveReactions" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for helping to solve my problem. I’ve missed few things in my OP. Please excuse me. Actually my reactions table contains different types of likes eg: type like or love. So can you please suggest how can I get likes count and love count separately also I need it’s relations like reactions and each reaction holds user so I need user relation to be populated on each reaction. How can I achieve this? I’ve updated my OP

Comment: Awesome this solves most of my problems which I've been struggling for so long. Just one lost query I also need to populate nested relations but for now I only get one level relation. user > reactions but what I also want is the nested relation of each reaction. Each reaction holds user ids for eg. likedBy or user. How can I populate these please