# Mongoose/Express - Counting number of likes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose/Express app with a Blogs Schema, where other users can 'like' the blogs.  In the Blogs Index, I would like to sort by the number of likes each blog has.

In the Blogs Schema, I have added a field called noOfLikes, but I'm unsure how to implement the count under the Blogs Controller (or elsewhere) to allow me to sort the records by noOfLikes.

**Blog Schema with likes and noOfLikes fields (other fields removed for simplicity):**

```
let blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   comments: [
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Comment"
      }   
   ],
   likes: [
      {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "User"
      }
   ],
   noOfLikes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Blog", blogSchema);
```

**Blog Controller, sorting by noOfLikes not currently working as unsure how to implement likes count in controller:**

```
    async blogIndexAll (req, res, next) {

        blogs = await Blog.find().sort({ 'noOfLikes': -1 });

        res.render("blogViews/blog", {blogs, cloudinary, currentUser: req.user});
    },
```

Comment: is `queryObject` undefined here or just left out for brevity?

Comment: sorry yes it's left out for brevity - it is defined

Comment: have removed to avoid confusion, thanks for flagging

Comment: Hi @ippi I think the code that is there is correct, though don't I require another line that links the Likes field to the noOfLikes field?  Otherwise how does the noOfLikes field know what it is supposed to be counting?  Thanks

Comment: sorry, I meant if you have `[{ noOflikes:10},{ noOflikes:5}]` and then plug it into some grid component, you might never be the wiser if the front-end shows you the wrong order, but your backend actually outputs the correct order all along. So I was just  making sure that you had made sure the output is actually incorrect.

Comment: When I look at my code I always use the `.exec();` after my sorts. I don't think it matters, but there are not many things that could be wrong here. Have you doublechecked your data, that you have numbers instead of strings. Perhaps the schema was changed after you saved some data?

Comment: Currently noOfLikes is just returning 0 (the default value) for every record, which I think as mentioned is because the two fields are not currently linked and hence the count of the likes it not being implemented

Comment: Thanks I have also tried including .exec() though no different

Comment: Ah I see, sorry for my reading incomprehension. I thought there was a problem with the sort.  ]

Comment: I would think i need something like noOfLikes = likes.length, but i don't know the correct syntax for this or where exactly I should put it

Comment: Instead of a find, you can use an Aggregation. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61304221/1497533

Comment: Thanks, though I'm not very clear how this would work in the context of my controller?  I feel like there should be a very simple solution here to just assigned likes.length to noOfLikes but i've been unable to conclude the syntax in the controller

Comment: Sorry, I'm on a stupid streak, sorry for wasting your time. I believe you either need to Aggregate using $size, https://stackoverflow.com/a/32064160/1497533. Or first grab the items into an array and sort them without the help of mongoose (ie `blogs = blogs.sort((a,b)=>b.likes.length- a.likes.length)`)

Comment: Or you could store the number of likes on the document each time you save. (see I am brilliant after all)

Comment: Haha @ippi I never doubted it for a second! :D. I've finally managed to find a solution based on your last response `(ie blogs = blogs.sort((a,b)=>b.likes.length- a.likes.length)))`so thank you for that!  Not sure how to mark as the answer as its a comment only, but please let me know if that's possible!

Comment: Alright, I made it into an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort it without the help of mongoose after your query has executed.

For example:

```
blogs = await Blog.find({}).exec();
// Using Array.prototype.sort
blogs = blogs.sort( (a,b) => b.likes.length - a.likes.length );
```